# How can I see the last SQL statement executed in Oracle database 11g r2?

Tags: oracle11g, trace

I am new to oracle database.

Can someone give me an example of the steps for how to see the last statements executed on the Oracle database 11g r2?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the below query to get the last sql executed based on last sql which was active in database

```
select ltrim(sq.sql_text)
  from v$sql sq, v$session se, v$open_cursor oc
 where sq.sql_id = oc.sql_id
   and se.saddr = oc.saddr
   and se.sid = oc.sid
   and se.audsid = SYS_CONTEXT('userenv', 'sessionid')
 order by oc.LAST_SQL_ACTIVE_TIME desc;
```

You can also use the below to find the last query executed in your session.

```
  SELECT (SELECT t2.sql_fulltext
    FROM   v$sql t2
    WHERE  t1.prev_sql_id = t2.sql_id
           AND t1.prev_child_number = t2.child_number) sql_fulltext
   FROM   v$session t1
   WHERE  t1.audsid = Sys_context('userenv', 'sessionid');
```

Comment: please elaborate

Answer (score 6):

You can use the below query:

```
SELECT program_id, program_line#, sql_text
FROM V$SQL VS , ALL_USERS AU
WHERE (executions >= 1)
AND (parsing_user_id != 0)
AND (AU.user_id(+) = VS.parsing_user_id)
AND UPPER(AU.USERNAME)  IN (UPPER('YourUser'))
ORDER BY last_active_time DESC;
```

if you need to know the statements of an PL/SQL object were executed then use or join with

```
select *
    from   dba_objects
    where object_id = program_id
```

Answer (score 3):

Find all sql where sql is like ....

```
select h.sample_time
, u.username
, h.machine
, s.sql_text
, h.*
from dba_hist_active_sess_history h
inner join v$sql s
on s.sql_id = h.sql_id
left outer join dba_users u
on u.user_id = h.user_id
where s.sql_text like 'DELETE%'
order by h.sample_time desc;
```

You need to be connected as sysdba user for this sql

Answer (score 1):

A couple of hints:

- In SQLplus, type a semicolon+ to see, and slash to execute again
- In SQLdeveloper, use F8
- If you mean see other users' statements then it's not possible by default.

  - You can configure AUDIT.
  - You can see some SQL statements in   `SELECT * FROM V$SQLAREA;`

Answer (score 1):

Connect as SYS user and execute the following query

```
select sql_text from v$sql where first_load_time=(select max(first_load_time) from v$sql) ;
```

Comment: @g00dy - I did have a chuckle at this one. :)

Comment: I had something like that in mind when I saw it actually: `SELECT distinct /*AvoidMe*/first_value(sql_text) OVER(ORDER BY FIRST_LOAD_TIME desc) FROM v$sql where sql_text not like '%AvoidMe%'`

Answer (score 1):

```
select sq.PARSING_SCHEMA_NAME, sq.LAST_LOAD_TIME, sq.ELAPSED_TIME, sq.ROWS_PROCESSED, ltrim(sq.sql_text)
  from v$sql sq, v$session se
 where sq.PARSING_SCHEMA_NAME = 'YOUR_SCHEMA'
 order by sq.LAST_LOAD_TIME desc;
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.