# how to get select statement query which was used to create table in oracle

Tags: oracle

I created a table in oracle like

```
CREATE TABLE suppliers AS (SELECT * FROM companies  WHERE id > 1000);
```

I would like to know the complete select statement which was used to create this table. 

I have already tried get_ddl but it is not giving the select statement. Can you please let me know how to get the select statement?

Comment: I don't understand. Did you forget what select statement you originally typed in, and you're trying to figure it out? Or did you just want to know what columns `select * from companies` expanded to?

Comment: user_tab_cols??

Comment: @kfinity Yes, I forget what select statement i typed in. It was a big query, which was joining three, four tables.

Comment: The SELECT statement isn't saved anywhere. Best of luck.

Comment: @BobJarvis, Thanks Bob.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205234/how-can-i-see-the-last-sql-statement-executed-in-oracle-database-11g-r2 or if you are using TOAD click F8 on the editor to see a history of sql

Comment: Like Bob Jarvis said - you can't get that statement from Oracle, it is not saved in DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're lucky one of these statements will show the DDL used to generate the table:

```
select *
from gv$sql
where lower(sql_fulltext) like '%create table suppliers%';

select *
from dba_hist_sqltext
where lower(sql_text) like '%create table%';
```

I used the word lucky because `GV$SQL` will usually only have results for a few hours or days, until the data is purged from the shared pool.  `DBA_HIST_SQLTEXT` will only help if you have AWR enabled, the statement was run in the last X days that AWR is configured to hold data (the default is 8), the statement was run *after* the last snapshot collection (by default it happens every hour), and the statement ran long enough for AWR to think it's worth saving.

And for each table Oracle does not always store the full SQL.  For security reasons, DDL statements are often truncated in the data dictionary.  Don't be surprised if the text suddenly cuts off after the first N characters.

And depending on how the SQL is called the case and space may be different.  Use `lower` and lots of wildcards to increase the chance of finding the statement.

Answer (score 0):

### TRY THIS:

```
 select distinct table_name
 from
 all_tab_columns where column_name in
 (
 select column_name from
  all_tab_columns    
 where table_name ='SUPPLIERS'
 )
```

you can find table which created from table

Comment: Thanks Ersin but I don't want table name, I need complete Select SQL statement which was used to create the table. 
Thanks again for your answer.